# Center justified text if it doesn't cover the full width of element

Tags: css

I have `text-align` set to `justify`:

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
  border:1px solid;
}

div {
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    NAME
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis imperdiet molestie enima
  </p>
</div>
```

How can I make it so if the length of the first line does *not* reach the right side of the element, then it is centered? So in the example above, `NAME` would be centered rather than aligned to the left.

Unfortunately, I can't adjust the setup of the element (can't wrap `NAME` into centered span tag etc). And the width is not fixed (above is just to illustrate the issue).

Comment: That is not really possible. `text-align-last` exists to do this for the last line (or the line before an explicit line break), but there is no counterpart for the first line. And while the `::first-line` pseudo class exists, that can't be used to specify `text-align`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `text-align-last: center;`

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
  border:1px solid;
  padding: 0 auto;
  text-align-last: center;
}

div {
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    NAME
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis imperdiet molestie enima
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This only works partially. It works on the NAME, because there is a forced line break after that - but it will also still work on the actual last line. It doesn't show in this specific example constellation, but shorten the text to stop after `Duis imperdiet`, and it will become clearly visible.

Comment: @CBroe Ah you are right. Do you have an alternative solution?

Comment: No, like I already commented, I don't think there currently is a CSS-only solution for this. _If_ the NAME part was static and known beforehand, then you could "hide" it using `p::first-line ( color: transparent; }` - and insert it again using a pseudo element with `content: "NAME"`, then you would have something you could format independently of the rest - but I am guessing the situation probably isn't that static? If you can insert any custom scripting, then you could make JavaScript wrap the first line into a `span` of its own dynamically.